# CMake: How to link (ln) additional names after install?

Tags: cmake

I need to find a way to link additional names to an installed executable, after installing it.

The below example is close, except for two problems.  One, the linking is done after every target, not just the install.  Two, the links are created in the build directory, not in the install directory (I can probably add the paths necessary to do that, but it would then error out if done before the install.)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
add_executable(gr gr.c)
install(TARGETS gr DESTINATION bin)
add_custom_command(
  TARGET gr
  POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ln;-f;gr;grm
  COMMAND ln;-f;gr;grs
  COMMAND ln;-f;gr;grh
)
```

What's simple, clean way to do what I want?

In case it's not clear, the Makefile equivalent is:

```
gr:  gr.c
    cc -o gr gr.c

install:
    install gr ${BINDIR}
    ln -f ${BINDIR}/gr ${BINDIR}/grm
    ln -f ${BINDIR}/gr ${BINDIR}/grs
    ln -f ${BINDIR}/gr ${BINDIR}/grh
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I have done in similar situations is use the custom command similar to what you have done, but add an additional `install` command to install the links in the final bin directory alongside the target. So after your `add_custom_command`:

```
install(
  FILES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/grm
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/grs
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/grh
  DESTINATION bin
)
```

Of course, this will probably only do what you expect if you change your links to symbolic links (ln -s).

Comment: That works, if I add `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/grm` etc. to the FILES being listed.  Also have to add a PERMISSIONS clause to make them executable.  And, as you said, change them to symbolic links.  I'd prefer hard links, but if that's going to be really complicated, this might be the best solution.  Thanks.